# What's the source of the approximation $\pi\approx\sqrt [4]{9^2+\frac{19^2}{22}}$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, pi

I found this approximation of $\pi$ in my math textbook, and I don't know where it comes from (or even how the person came up with this):
$$\pi\approx \sqrt [4]{9^2+\frac{19^2}{22}}$$
Can someone tell me where this is from and your thoughts on how the person came up with this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the expression has $8$ arbitrary digits and some calculations, and manages to give $9$ digits of $\pi$.  It shouldn't be much of a coincidence that such things are possible

Comment: The approximation appears to be a simplification of one attributed to Ramanujan. (See the Wikipedia's ["Approximations of $\pi$" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_π#Miscellaneous_approximations).) The original form is $$\sqrt[4]{3^4+2^4+\frac{1}{2+(2/3)^2}}$$

Comment: If you change the question in such a way that it invalidates one of the comments or answers, you should make that visible. The comment above by Blue no longer makes sense because you removed the part of the question where you'd asked how the approximation is computed.

Comment: The underlying idea behind this is simple continued fraction of $\pi^4$.

Comment: A very good approximation for the price of a more complicated expression than $\ \frac{355}{113}\ $ , which is only good to $6$ digits compared to $8$ digits.

Answer (score 3):

Writing as continued fraction:

$$ \pi^4 =[97;2,2,4,-16541,\dots] $$

This means stopping expansion after 4 gives a really good rational approximation, namely

$$\pi^4 \approx 97+\frac9{22}$$

Rest is writing it more neatly as $\pi^4\approx 9^2+\cdots$

Comment: I don't know about "more neatly", but $97+\frac{9}{22}$ is seven symbols (counting the fraction bar) and $9^2+\frac{19^2}{22}$ is nine. So I would say your version is the simpler.